# Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3 found 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, ide

In android studio I keep getting this error message when building. 
I've tried 
deleting the **.gradle** file multiple times and restarting the IDE but the error doesn't seem to stop.

I made sure that I've updated EVERYTHING there is in SDK's and other things it required.

Comment: When you create a new template project do you get the same error?

Comment: yep I've created 3 new projects and deleting the previous one but same error!

Comment: I don't mind uninstalling and reinstalling the software but for the past 2 days i've wasted a lot of time downloading it's files like SDK's and whatever files that are more than 2GB of data that took me ages. Is there a way to reinstall and keep these files to reuse?

Comment: Try to restart your computer. Once, i got this problem, and tried same things nothing worked and then after restarting my computer solved the problem.

Comment: You can check this. Hope it will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924883/18858169

Comment: You can check this. Hope it will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924883/18858169

Answer (score 1):

I've tried several solution -

**First Solution:** Go to File -> Invalid Chaches/Restart...

**Second Solution:** First, Build -> Clean Project and the Build -> Rebuild Project

**Third Solution:** First close the project and remove from workspace of Android Studio, then Go to C:\Users\user.gradle then delete .gradle folder. After that Open the project again.

*But none of them worked! Then i got a solution, which worked in my case, the solution is bellow -*

[In my case, the problem was in gradle version. Check your Gradle version File -> Project Structure(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) and Plugin version also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9DKc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the XXX.Lock file, and rerun the project. You should be able to find the location of this .lock file in the error message

Answer (score 0):

is solved mine by downloading the latest version the latest version of gradle distribution.

> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).