# gradle Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0

Tags: android-studio, gradle

getting "Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0" error when trying to debug even after following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010547/errorunexpected-lock-protocol-found-in-lock-file-expected-3-found-0) and deleting the .gradle folder
current gradle version is 4.4 and android studio 3.1.2

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution which i think is much better.

1. Go to project structure Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S and select Project from left menu if it is not already selected.
2. Select latest Android Gradle Plugin Version
3. Select Gradle Version to the latest stable one.
4. Select Apply.
5. List item

P.S It is better to Update gradle to latest stable version.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This error normally occurs when your system mistakenly shut down and the project is building. Here is the solution:

> close the project
>
> delete the project from Android Studio list
>
> Close Android Studio
>
> delete the .gradle folder from the root of your project
>
> Run Android Studio again
>
> Open existing Android Studio project

Or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858809/7414213)

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest & most easy way to solve this issue**

This error generally occurs when we update our android studio version or make changes in previous projects. I don't know why but it comes randomly. I follow many ways to solve this but ill figure out the easiest way to tackle this.

- First, go to the android studio, then click on File.
- Second, go to the project structure & Click the project tab.
- Third, most imp step -> check the (Gradle Version) of yours (In my case my previous is 6.5 & latest one is 6.8.1) if it is the previous one, not the latest, then select the latest one..... remember not to select (beta) select only **stable release**. & (Apply) then (OK) -> your project start downloading files & I hope your problem gets solved. Just like mine. Check Images for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Main Solution : The most effective solution in my case was change `distributionUrl` (go to `gradle-wrapper.properties`) to latest version like below.**

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```

**Second Solution** : invalid cache and restart.

**Third Solution** : Clean Project Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 0):

The error
Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
was recurring in my every project after build on 3 or 4th time. I sepnd 3-4 days to correct it through google search, but could not solve it. Then some hint is got in search and I changed as below screens:

And the error gone[gradle setting at the time of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoXVH.jpg)
[Gradle changed which ractify the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S8Au.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue it took me few steps:

-go to C:\Users[username] and delete the .gradle folder

-go to the project folder and delete the .gradle folder

-inside the project folder execute gradlew.bat

Answer (score -1):

Don't use different Gradle versions for building a project!
Make sure that `gradlew build` and `gradle build` use the same version.

Comment: What makes you think that this is done by OP? And if they actually do, how would fixing that be done?